# Python tkinter прозрачность фона

Tags: python, tkinter

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: мне нужно получить в tkinter прозрачный фон. Если ставлю прозрачность фона на максимум командой `root.attributes("-alpha", 0)`, то, логично, пропадают все элементы типа Label и т.д. Мне нужно, чтобы при запуске программы на экране просто появлялся текст. Нашел в интернете и адаптировал  похожую программу:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
#-----------------------------------CONFIG-------------------
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.lift()
root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
root.geometry("+10+670")
#-----------------------------------Labels-------------------
text1 = "Text1: " + "this is tryal command. It was used only to understand 
style of a window."
text2 = "Text2: " + "this is tryal command. It was used only to understand 
style of a window. White space above"
lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text=text1, font='Arial 15', fg="Red", bg='gray')
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text=text2, font='Arial 15', fg="Red", bg='gray')
lbl3 = tk.Label(root, text='sdfghjk', font='Arial 15', fg="Red", bg='white')
lbl1.pack()
lbl2.pack()
#----------------------------------------------------------
lbl1.mainloop()
```

Однако, здесь я не могу разбить текст на две группы, чтобы, к примеру, одна часть была внизу экрана, а другая - слева. Также имеется и другой недостаток: если один текст больше другого (как в примере), то рядом с меньшим текстом появляется белая область. Умные люди, исправьте, пожалуйста, а то я весь интернет облазил - похожего не нашел, там лишь фотографии вставляют, а не тексты... или, может, кто-нибудь знает библиотеку, с помощью которой можно это осуществить.

Answer (score 2):

Сам измучился пытаясь это сделать.Я уж думал что на моем macos  этого не как не сделать но нашел вариант.

### Под Windows:

```
import Tkinter as tk # Python 2
import tkinter as tk # Python 3
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, image='text', bg='white',font=["Comic Sans MS",30])
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("+250+250")
root.lift()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
label.pack()
label.mainloop()
```

<sub>Сам на маке — не пробовал</sub>

### Следующий вариант

должен работать под **mac** / **linux**(или **ubuntu** и т.д....) (т.е **unix-подобные ОС**).
Но на моем маке это не сработало:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
# Hide the root window drag bar and close button
root.overrideredirect(True)
# Make the root window always on top
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
# Turn off the window shadow
root.wm_attributes("-transparent", True)
# Set the root window background color to a transparent color
root.config(bg='systemTransparent')

root.geometry("+300+300")
label = tk.Label(root, text="hello")
# Set the label background color to a transparent color
label.config(bg='systemTransparent')
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

<sub>Но на моем маке это не сработало</sub>

И наконец мой третий вариант который *сработал* у меня на **маке**:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
w=Tk()
w2 = Toplevel(w)
w2.geometry("550x400")
w2.geometry("+300+300")
w2.wm_overrideredirect(True)  # Removes the titlrbar and borders
w2.update()   # Don't need if not on macos
w2.lift()
w2.attributes('-alpha', 1) # Makes the window transparent
w2.attributes('-topmost', 1)
w2.wm_attributes('-transparent', True)
w2.config(bg='systemTransparent')
w.attributes("-alpha",0)
w.iconify()
l=Label(w2,text="✅Congratulation! Programm is starting...",font=["Times",30],fg="green")
l.pack()
l=Label(w2)
l.pack()
pbar=ttk.Progressbar(w2)
pbar.pack()
pbar.start()
b=ttk.Button(w2,text="quit",command=quit)
b.pack()
w.mainloop()
```