# Как сделать прозрачный фон Frame и Label в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Нужно сделать фон Frame и Label прозрачными, т.к. на фоне окна стоит картинка. Если присвоить Frame фон окна обрезанный до нужного пикселя, то появляется белый зазор(см. скрин). Как это можно сделать?

[image: Скрин окна с зазором]

Comment: Возможно, [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989973/python-tkinter-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) вам поможет

Comment: Label и Frame не поддерживают прозрачность. Если нужен текст с прозрачным фоном - то это делается через Canvas и create_text на нем. Но не факт что это решит проблему с белой рамкой, возможно придется все окно делать через Canvas, и вместо фреймов использовать create_window (нечто похожее на фреймы, но для Canvas).

Comment: @h4cktivist, к сожалению не помогает, т.к. Frame не имеет метода .wm_attributes()

Comment: @insolor, ок, спасибо, буду разбираться

Answer (score -1):

Замени цвет виджетов на while и добавь код`root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")`

Comment: К сожалению это не поможет, т.к. Tkinter в таком случае вырезает всё безотказно. То есть есть у меня Label с белым цветом, значит и фон за ним тоже вырежется. Проблему уже решил через Canvas, как и написанно было в комментариях